# Line integrals and invariance of parameterization

Tags: line-integrals

The line integral of a scalar function $f(x,y)$ along a curve $\vec{r}(t)$ for $a \leq t \leq b$ is defined to be
$$
\int\limits_{\vec{r}(t)} f(\vec{r}(t)) \, ds = \int_a^b f(\vec{r}(t)) \, ||\vec{r}\,'(t)|| \, dt
$$
and my Calculus text says this definition is invariant of the parameterization of $\vec{r}(t)$.

Thus, since the two curves
$$
\vec{r}_1(t) = \langle t,t^2 \rangle \; (0 \leq t \leq 1) \quad \text{and} \quad \vec{r}_2(t) =\langle t^2,t^4 \rangle \; (0 \leq t \leq 1)
$$
determine exactly the same curve (when restricted to $t \in [0,1]$), the corresponding line integrals should be the same, but they aren't (let's just use $f(x,y) = 1$ for simplicity):
$$
\int\limits_{\vec{r}_1(t)} f(\vec{r}_1(t)) \, ds = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+4t^2} \, dt \approx 1.09 \\
\int\limits_{\vec{r}_2(t)} f(\vec{r}_2(t)) \, ds = \int_0^1 \sqrt{4t^2+16t^6} \, dt \approx 1.48.
$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: The two integrals are exactly the same via the substitution $x = t^2$. They are both $\approx 1.48$

Comment: Perhaps you may see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635224/line-integral-doesnt-depend-on-parametrization).

Comment: Oh my gosh, yes I just made a typo in Matlab.  Sigh.... Well at least I didn't break all of mathematics.